# pyautogui automation doesn't work with Zoom

Tags: python, automation

I am working on a script to automate zoom meeting login, but on running the code, only the zoom app opens and nothing happens after that. The code then runs when i close the zoom app

```
import keyboard, mouse, time, subprocess
subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\Prathamesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom")
time.sleep(3)
x = [683, 577, 525, 709, 572, 700]
y = [360, 323, 483, 523, 325, 519]
for i in range(6):
     mouse.move(x[i], y[i])
mouse.click()
if i == 1:
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.write("meetingid")
elif i == 4:
    time.sleep(3)
    keyboard.write("password")
elif i == 5:
    time.sleep(5)
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Probably not relevant to the problem but your code indentation seems to be off...

Comment: if that's the case, my code editor should have warned me, right?

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,

I think that your problem derives from the fact that the `subprocess.call()` command waits for the task to be completed or terminated in order to let the program continue, according to the documentation for the library.

Here is the python documentation for the subprocess library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

The thing is that python is not multi-threaded and thus the program's flow is stopped until the function you are executing ends. What I would do, would be to import the threading library and use it to call a function that executes the command.

Something like this:

```
import keyboard, mouse, time, subprocess
from threading import Thread

def OpenZoom():
  subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\Prathamesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom")

thrd = Thread(target=OpenZoom)
thrd.start()

time.sleep(3)

x = [683, 577, 525, 709, 572, 700]
y = [360, 323, 483, 523, 325, 519]
for i in range(6):
    mouse.move(x[i], y[i])
    mouse.click()
    if i == 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        keyboard.write("meetingid")
    elif i == 4:
        time.sleep(3)
        keyboard.write("password")
    elif i == 5:
        time.sleep(5)
    time.sleep(3)
```

I hope this answers your question.